# BeautifulSoup fundamentals

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need help with my Twitter bot that will auto tweet every hour (i have sorted out all the api and stuff so its all good). But i cannot seem to be able to run BeautifulSoup the way i intend to and i get the same error everytime. found = soup.find (almost at the end of the code) won't work (because i am new to bs4).

What am i doing wrong?

```
# model scraping for spacepics

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
import tweepy as tp 
import time

#Posting to twitter
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''

# login to twitter account api
auth = tp.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tp.API(auth)


while True:
    #Get Bitcoin Price
    url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'

    # download page for parsing
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
    found = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left'}). find("span", {"class" : "text-large2"})

    #Update Twitter
    status = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ") +  "Bitcoin price currently at $" + found.text + " coinmarketcap.com"
    api.update_status(status)
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: What error do you get? At what line?

Comment: line 28, in <module>
    found = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left'}). find("span", {"class" : "text-large2"})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
@AlanWik

Comment: Thats because the first find did not find anything (NoneType), and you can't use the find method over a None result.

Comment: @AlanWik Yeah i got that part... but im unsure where to go on from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use the following code it would return the correct price:

```
found = soup.find(attrs= {'class':'priceValue___11gHJ'})
```

Comment: Yeah that worked... i had to inspect the web page rather than using a tool i had before to find each div and copy and paste it around... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the error is at this line:

```
found = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left'}). find("span", {"class" : "text-large2"})
```

try to not use spaces after calling a method (the last find):

```
found = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left'}).find("span", {"class" : "text-large2"})
```

Comment: Deleted the space but still more or less the same error :  found = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left'}).find("span", {"class" : "text-large2"})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 1):

Coinmarketcap has it's own API accesses which you can use for free so you don't have to parse the outputs. https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out! Did not know they had that!